# Chrome WebRTC breaks on browser update with adapter.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

I suddenly get the following error on my webapp when using chrome:

```
Failed to construct 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to initialize native PeerConnection.
```

I believe it was because of a chrome update

I'm using adapter.js v1.0.2(latest)

This doesn't occur in firefox. I think it's because of my constraints object. Here it is

```
options = {
        iceServers:[
            {
                url:'stun:12.345.678.910:3478'
            },

            {
                url: "turn:@12.345.678.910:3479",
                username:"ninefingers", 
                credential:"youhavetoberealistic"
            }
        ]
    };
```

I made sure the turn server was running. I think the options object format has changed. Using chrome 48.0.2564.116 on ubuntu and mac os x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that this is an `adapter.js` issue, in your ice server config for turn url, there is an unnecessary `@`, that must be the issue. Probably firefox just ignores it, but chrome is more strict, change code to:

```
  ...
  urls: "turn:12.345.678.910:3479",
  ...
```

**Edit:** based on jib's comment that `url` is deprecated and must be replaced with `urls`, the new code would be:

```
options = {
    iceServers:[
        {
            urls:'stun:12.345.678.910:3478'
        },

        {
            urls: "turn:12.345.678.910:3479",
            username:"ninefingers", 
            credential:"youhavetoberealistic"
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Works for me. Also, I would rename `url` to [`urls`](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#idl-def-RTCIceServer) as the former is deprecated (though it still works).